# В чём причина исчезновения игрового объекта, когда он приближается к краю экрана в Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Если посмотреть видео: https://youtu.be/K2TIe38Qarc
Можно увидеть, что объект исчезает до того, как полностью уйдёт за экран.
Есть предположение - что это Occlusion culling, но я не нашел там ничего.

Сама камера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытался крутить и клацать то, что я обвёл синим и красным, но безуспешно.

Если есть способ решения, буду рад любой помощи.
Если что-то не понятно - спрашивайте.

Answer (score 1):

Решение было проще, чем я думал. Она заключалось в Skinned Mesh Renderer(нужно было включить "Update When Offscreen").

Comment: Примите свой ответ :)